# Formatting body on a POST request

Tags: go

So I copied the chrome post request as curl and used https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/ to turn it into golang

I'm currently trying to add my own variables for all of the options and I'm not sure how to do this as it's above my level of formatting

For each questionID I want to add my own variable
Hopefully this makes sense

```
body := strings.NewReader("{\"startDate\":\"2021-09-21T10:40:39.469Z\",\"submitDate\":\"2021-09-21T10:41:23.846Z\",\"answers\":\"[{\"questionId\":\"r28aff279baf24e929f1299218243e021\",\"answer1\":\"Misselar Gunchar\"},{\"questionId\":\"rafb83da5acd64939900728cb48b7c43f\",\"answer1\":\"CEG01848592\"},{\"questionId\":\"rc095894394a24855a4d77359184db1e3\",\"answer1\":\"Year 10\"},{\"questionId\":\"r9d887d623c18456999d435e0d283548c\",\"answer1\":\"13DM\"},{\"questionId\":\"r818e0bda482a46a5a22f6685a347b7cc\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r89821d900d134b7ba93a61f5149c9634\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"rf1763918ee9b40f5bf1c7a5604b4ee39\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r9d43a44a73704544adac2972ba676ff7\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"raef4f4bf69db49ec829e54a053e3df06\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"rca9debf8091b474a910e6621940cd7ce\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"rbe974138760544df9792e48626d436fa\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r05755481374e4fcbb59e2df04b7fffa7\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r83b60eb3a130454ca3a449f4d4c34378\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r912b8ec9ff3b40a9bdc24561a1aa7085\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r1ef19b4f232c418fa5a3e42d19ead891\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"rf2510a7ff51f4078aec0647f6abd2eb1\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r57f974edac2149838efda7e773915b96\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r9b4ab53ce8a94287b10e5a3191455ef1\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r091672ed02184572874115534c620ab4\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r1c3373e66e0a434ab8e273bda6d4a4b7\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"ra5ac314998664a9980918b76552c9dd6\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r01c4cb1e3eb042218364d69fea80b709\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"rbd791e3eb0f749189ffb12cf5a0b1d7a\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r389fb40b5d0c42ac99657c5ea7d42cec\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r1e3a066a95834f03878242c212b50c9d\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"re2400deb6d5d4bccb6c4fbafef08b6c0\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r58dd083743134508be9943d2a3de49c2\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r5d9573b510ec484db2c9d05387212fac\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"rfa8d0127236c4408a979a5b85ff48303\",\"answer1\":1}]\",\"emailReceiptConsent\":false}")
```

For example, I have a function in my code that creates a first and last name as a string, I'd like this to replace "Misselar Gunchar"

Full code:

```
    body := strings.NewReader("{\"startDate\":\"2021-09-21T10:40:39.469Z\",\"submitDate\":\"2021-09-21T10:41:23.846Z\",\"answers\":\"[{\"questionId\":\"r28aff279baf24e929f1299218243e021\",\"answer1\":\"Misselar Gunchar\"},{\"questionId\":\"rafb83da5acd64939900728cb48b7c43f\",\"answer1\":\"CEG01848592\"},{\"questionId\":\"rc095894394a24855a4d77359184db1e3\",\"answer1\":\"Year 10\"},{\"questionId\":\"r9d887d623c18456999d435e0d283548c\",\"answer1\":\"13DM\"},{\"questionId\":\"r818e0bda482a46a5a22f6685a347b7cc\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r89821d900d134b7ba93a61f5149c9634\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"rf1763918ee9b40f5bf1c7a5604b4ee39\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r9d43a44a73704544adac2972ba676ff7\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"raef4f4bf69db49ec829e54a053e3df06\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"rca9debf8091b474a910e6621940cd7ce\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"rbe974138760544df9792e48626d436fa\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r05755481374e4fcbb59e2df04b7fffa7\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r83b60eb3a130454ca3a449f4d4c34378\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r912b8ec9ff3b40a9bdc24561a1aa7085\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r1ef19b4f232c418fa5a3e42d19ead891\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"rf2510a7ff51f4078aec0647f6abd2eb1\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r57f974edac2149838efda7e773915b96\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r9b4ab53ce8a94287b10e5a3191455ef1\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r091672ed02184572874115534c620ab4\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r1c3373e66e0a434ab8e273bda6d4a4b7\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"ra5ac314998664a9980918b76552c9dd6\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r01c4cb1e3eb042218364d69fea80b709\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"rbd791e3eb0f749189ffb12cf5a0b1d7a\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"r389fb40b5d0c42ac99657c5ea7d42cec\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r1e3a066a95834f03878242c212b50c9d\",\"answer1\":3},{\"questionId\":\"re2400deb6d5d4bccb6c4fbafef08b6c0\",\"answer1\":1},{\"questionId\":\"r58dd083743134508be9943d2a3de49c2\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"r5d9573b510ec484db2c9d05387212fac\",\"answer1\":2},{\"questionId\":\"rfa8d0127236c4408a979a5b85ff48303\",\"answer1\":1}]\",\"emailReceiptConsent\":false}")
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/19f17765-81d4-4ab4-b996-5298336a5a3d/users/425503a3-d3e7-457b-9c89-edd2d63109cc/forms(\\'ZXfxGdSBtEq5llKYM2paPaMDVULn03tFnInt0tYxCcxURVRRSjVPTjNRU0s3MlhaTEY5T0dDRU5FTS4u\\')/responses", body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authority", "forms.office.com")
    req.Header.Set("Pragma", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Ch-Ua", "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"93\", \" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"93\"")
    req.Header.Set("Odata-Version", "4.0")
    req.Header.Set("X-Correlationid", "correlation id")
    req.Header.Set("X-Usersessionid", "session id")
    req.Header.Set("X-Ms-Form-Request-Ring", "business")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile", "?0")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("Odata-Maxverion", "4.0")
    req.Header.Set("__requestverificationtoken", "verification token")
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "user agent")
    req.Header.Set("X-Ms-Form-Request-Source", "ms-formweb")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform", "\"Windows\"")
    req.Header.Set("Origin", "https://forms.office.com")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "cors")
    req.Header.Set("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "empty")
    req.Header.Set("Referer", "form link")
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8")
    req.Header.Set("Cookie", "cookier")

    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
```

Comment: Just add them as per what you already have

Comment: I'm running this program multiple times, with different names from a list. Trying to prove to my teacher I can submit names and CEG numbers with all club requests pulled from a .txt

Comment: You have a JSON body you want to POST. Can you show what `go` code you've tried so far & maybe we can help.

Comment: Edited to have the rest of the code, my bad

Comment: You might want to take a minute and reflect on posting cookies, tokens and session ids online.

Comment: Okay yes that was not very clever, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your JSON body has some formatting (extra `"` etc.) issues rendering it invalid.

Here's what I suggest:

- use an online resource like [json-pretty-print](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) to test your JSON input. Once you have corrected the general format, copy the output to the next step.
- you're already using use [curl-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/) to help generate your request, so use [json-to-go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to convert your JSON to a reusable go struct
- this yields this type:

---

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    StartDate  time.Time `json:"startDate"`
    SubmitDate time.Time `json:"submitDate"`
    Answers    []struct {
        QuestionID string `json:"questionId"`
        Answer1    string `json:"answer1"`
    } `json:"answers"`
    EmailReceiptConsent bool `json:"emailReceiptConsent"`
}
```

- give this type a sensible name
- create an instance of this struct
- fill in the fields
- `json.Marshal` the data:

---

```
type answers struct { /* */ } // struct from above

var data answers
// fill in data fields

bs, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

body =  bytes.NewBuffer(bs)
```

Comment: Mind giving me an example of "fill in data fields", my knowledge of structs is rusty to say the least, hence I tried the more difficult / wrong way

Comment: I've shown you how you can dynamically generate a request body - filling the request is a code-writing exercise meant for the developer.